# Mean-value inequality with several variables

Tags: derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Let $f(\mathbf{x})$ be a real-valued and continuously differentiable
function on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $|
\partial_{x_i} f(\mathbf{x}) | \leqslant M$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in U$
and all $i=1$, $\dots$, $d$ for some finite constant $M$.  If
$\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ are points in $U$ and such that the
segment joining them is included in $U$, we have

$$ 
  |f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x}')|
  \leqslant M \, \| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}' \|. 
$$

So if $U$ is convex the inequality holds for all couples of
points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ in $U$. I believe that the "for all $\mathbf{x}$,
$\mathbf{x}'$" result holds as well if $U$
is arcwise connected yet could
not find a reference for such a result. Is this true, and if yes, what
reference can be cited for this? If no, what other condition on $U$ weaker
than convexity could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. Let $n=2$ and $U = (B_2 \setminus B_{1/2}) \setminus \Gamma $ where $\Gamma = \{(x,0) \text{ s.t. } x>0\}$ which is an annulus minus the positive $x$-axis. Then let $u:U \to (0,2\pi)$ be given in polar coordinates by $u(x,y) = \theta(x,y)$ with $\theta$ being the angle in the range $(0,2\pi)$ the point $(x,y)$ makes with the positive $x$-axis when measured anticlockwise from the positive $x$-axis (i.e. the principle angle). Then  $$\vert u(1+h,0)-u(1-h,0) \vert \to 2\pi \qquad \text{as }h\to 0, $$ but $$\| (1+h,0)-(1-h,0)\|=2h \to 0 \qquad \text{as }h\to 0.$$

As for other conditions you could impose on $U$ to make this work, without further context it is hard to give you a very good answer (For example, I could let $\mathscr F$ be the collection of open sets for which the inequality holds then say that the condition you seek is $U \in \mathscr F$, but this is obviously not very helpful).

At least an assumption on $U$ that prevents my counter-example above is the following: let $U$ be path-connected and define the metric

$$ d(x, y) = \inf \{ \ell (\gamma) \text{ s.t. } \gamma \in C^1([0,1];U), \gamma(0)=x, \gamma (1)=y\}$$ where $\ell (\gamma)$ denotes the arc-length of $\gamma$. Suppose that there exists $C>0$ such $$d(x,y) \leqslant C\|x-y \| \qquad \text{for all } x,y\in U.  $$ Then $U$ will satisfy your inequality which can be seen by first applying the mean-value inequality for arc-length then using the assumption.

Comment: Thanks. Reading your answer I realize that  the question is about a metric concern, and arcwise connectedness is a topological property.

Comment: You're welcome :)